# Running Self-contained asp .net core application on RHEL v6

Tags: asp.net-core

Has anyone tried to get the application to work in terms of subj? I know that officially versions older than the 7 is not supported and I am not an expert on Linux, but still...

At the moment test app tells that

```
./WebApplication1: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./WebApplication1)
./WebApplication1: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by ./WebApplication1)
./WebApplication1: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./WebApplication1)
./WebApplication1: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./WebApplication1)
```

In addition, my server has no Internet access (that's why SCD)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you tried update `libstdc++.so`?

Comment: Without internet access i can't even do yum search. And as a person who sees Linux for the second time in my life updating libstdc++ manually seems a challenging task :)